# how to send request to soap web service using "volley library" in android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-volley

I'm trying to use Volley library to communicate with my Soap Web service.
    after searching i get only response for communicating with url, but i dont 
know how to send request to soap web service, which have url, Namespace and web 
method name etc, also i have to send parameters with request to get response, 
here i have example which only send request based on url

```
String url = "http://httpbin.org/html";

// Request a string response
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        // Result handling 
        System.out.println(response.substring(0,100));

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        // Error handling
        System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
        error.printStackTrace();

    }
});

// Add the request to the queue
Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```

currently requesting soap web service like,

```
public static String invokecreatepostfm(int posttypeid, byte[] picture,byte[] Fullimage,long postedbyid,String postcontent,String langitude,String latitude,String locationname,String webMethName, Context mContext) {           

        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
        SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + webMethName;
        // Property which holds input parameters

        request.addProperty("PostTypeID", posttypeid);
        request.addProperty("Picture", org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(picture));
        request.addProperty("FullImage", org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(Fullimage));
        request.addProperty("PostedByID", postedbyid);
        request.addProperty("PostContent", postcontent);
        request.addProperty("Langitude", langitude);
        request.addProperty("Latitude", latitude);
        request.addProperty("LocationName", locationname);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            LStatus = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            LStatus = e.toString();
        }
        //Return booleam to calling object
        return LStatus;
    }
```

i want to request soap web service using volley library but i don't know how to request this kind of soap web service using volley library, can anyone help me?thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this may help. But have a look here. https://gist.github.com/worker8/20eb5bd3400b88f10973

Comment: did you find any solution? i also want to implement soap using volley

Comment: NO i didn't find out any solutions for it..

Comment: I think volley is specifically designed to handle REST.